# How many possible combinations are there of 9 unique items arranged in groups of 4. Order not important.

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry if this isn't truly a combinatorics question - I'm a musician.  I need to arrange nine different names in groups of four each. The order in which the names appear doesn't matter. How many possible combinations are there?

Comment: What have you attempted towards solving the question?

Comment: It is indeed called the binomial coefficient, and the now deleted answer was correct.  It's also called $n$ choose $k$.

Answer (score 1):

${9\choose4}=126$ ways of choosing $4$ from $9$.  The formula is ${n\choose k}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.

There are $n!/(n-k)!$ permutations.  And each has $k!$ arrangements.

Comment: Thanks, Chris - works. Much fewer options than I'd have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna know how many ways you can arrange 9 unique objects in a group of 4?

Then this is equivalent to obtain all 4 element subsets of a set of order 9, which is ${9 \choose 4}= \frac{9!}{4! 5!}=126.$

Comment: Like it - grateful for people who have brains wired in this way!